# "Forms are disabled in Gmail"

Tags: android, spring-boot, gmail, thymeleaf

Android Gmail App Blocking input type submit. Anyone encountered this type of issue? Help.

[image]

Code :

```
<form th:action="${url}" th:object="${testToken}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:value="${unique}" name="theUrl" /> 
        <input th:style="'border:0; height:60px; width:150px; background:url(' + |cid:${imageResourceName}| + ') no-repeat left top; cursor:pointer;'"
            type="submit" value="" />
    </form>
```

Comment: probably that is how GMAIL works not allowing the forms to be part of the email due to some security reasons?

Comment: It's odd that Google Forms are only disable in Google gmail app in Google Android. All other combinations email/OS seem to work just fine.

Comment: it works on desktop browser

Comment: Even regular Google Forms (sent via email with the 'Include form in email' box checked) cause this error to appear in Gmail for Android.

Answer (score 2):

Change the method from "post" to "get" and it will work.

Discovered this by accident.